# Find two variable in terms of 6 other with 2 equalities available includes square root and square power

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following two equations :

$$\sqrt{(x_p-x_{a_1})^2+(y_p-y_{a_1})^2}+\sqrt{(x_p-x_{b_1})^2+(y_p-y_{b_1})^2}=D_1$$
$$\sqrt{(x_p-x_{a_2})^2+(y_p-y_{a_2})^2}+\sqrt{(x_p-x_{b_2})^2+(y_p-y_{b_2})^2}=D_2$$

I want to find $x_p$ and $y_p$ in terms of the other variables $x_{a_1} , y_{a_1} , x_{a_2} , y_{a_2}, D_1 , D_2$, can't solve it i don't know how

My attemp was by raising all sides to the power of 2 and then subtracting  the second equality from the first , that did'nt help alot

Comment: You should post the complete question and your attempt here.

Comment: Hint: you’re seeking intersection points of two ellipses...

Comment: i wasnt able to to post the image here thats way , i will be glad if you correct me

Comment: OK, I've included the equations above - (*click edit and see how it was done*).  You need to provide your attempt at solving as well.